# Как читать указанное количество строк из csv файла python3

Tags: python-3.x, csv, beautiful-soup

Задача состоит в том, чтобы читать нужную строку из файла products_links.csv и получать строку, чтобы в последствии использовать её в качестве URL.

Знаю, что код написан не правильно.
Изучив документацию тут - https://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/csv.html, я так и не понял, как мне сделать то, что нужно.

```
import csv

k = 0
n = 1
def read_csv(k,n):
    reader = csv.reader(open("products_links.csv", newline=''))
    next(reader) #Знаю, что пропускать fieldsname можно и нужно иначе, задача не в этом. 
    while k < n:
        d = (next(reader))
        k += 1
    return d
d = read_csv(k, n)
f = d[0]
print(f)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поставленную задачу удалось решить следующим образом:

```
import csv
with open('products_links.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    cont = [row for row in r]
    k = 3
    d = cont[k]
    print (d[0])
```

Код написан немного не в том виде, в котором он был изначально при постановке вопроса, однако, думаю, что ответ сможет натолкнуть ищущих на нужный путь.